# Image size inside table

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, html-table

I have a table with multiple data, including, title, description, an image etc. I want something like this:

[image]

Where the image fits the cell, and when the cell resizes, the image take 100% of the cell, but I get something like this:

[image]

How can I do it in? I'm using foundation by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The foundation.css (in the 'complete' download, at least) includes rules that give:
   img {height:auto; max-width: 100%;}
Using the developer tools of your browser, make sure these CSS rules are not overridden.